# How do I get the phone number of the contact that was clicked in Lync 2013?

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

I would like to know the proper way of getting the phone number that was clicked when right-clicking a contact in Lync and select call and then click on a number.

Expected is a tel string with the number that was clicked.

Could someone please outline the event we would use in that case and the code to retrieve the number?

At the moment I am using the `ConversationManager.ConversationAdded` event and retrieving the number from the contact endpoint URI but that only works half of the time as sometimes the default endpoint comes through as a SIP string even I clicked on the actual phone number.

Here the code.

```
Private Sub ConversationManager_ConversationAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManagerEventArgs) Handles m_lyncConversationManager.ConversationAdded

Dim ConvParticipants As IList(Of Participant) = e.Conversation.Participants
Dim ContactURI() As String = ConvParticipants.Item(1).Contact.Uri.ToString().Split(":")
If e.Conversation.Modalities(ModalityTypes.AudioVideo).State = ModalityState.Connecting Then

Dim outboundContact As Contact = ConvParticipants.Item(1).Contact
Dim _ContactSettings As IDictionary(Of ContactSetting, Object) = outboundContact.Settings
Dim outObject As Object = Nothing
Dim PhoneNumber() As String

If _ContactSettings.TryGetValue(ContactSetting.DefaultContactEndpoint, outObject) Then
PhoneNumber = DirectCast(outObject, ContactEndpoint).Uri.Split(":")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want this for Audio/Video call.

You have to get the Participant as you are doing but then you have to get the Modalities of that participant and there get the Endpoint.

C# code:

```
ContactEndpoint ep = Participant.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].Endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get a Sip Uri with a phone parameter like so: `sip:user@domain.ext;user=phone`. This tells your Lync server you want to initiate a phonecall with this user, and it will then decide how to route accordingly based on the information it has about that user.

If you want a telephone number, get the `ContactCard` for this contact, this contains (amongst other things) the phonenumber(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this won't work as you need to know the number that was actually clicked. The contact card will give me more than one number, so no way of knowing which number was actually clicked.